# Data-Vocabulary.org for product reviews -- Will reviews show up in search results?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, data-vocabulary.org

My question is about Data-Vocabulary.org vs Schema.org. I'm working on an e-commerce site right now and we've implemented product reviews.  The app we are using to do so structures the data with Data-Vocabulary.org, not Schema.org.

We want the star ratings to show up on Google searches for products, but as of now they aren't.

I know there is some Google magic sauce to how all of that works, but is there any reason that using Data-Vocabulary.org instead of Schema.org (which is how the rest of the site is structured) would prevent star ratings from showing on search results?